# python lstrip(' ') removes lines

Tags: python, arrays

first of all, I'm new to python, so maybe my code is a little weird or bordering to be wrong, but it works, so there is that.

I've been googleing for this problem, but can't find anyone who writes about, I got this huge list written like this

```
    1    2    3    4     5


    2    2    2    2     2


    3    3    3    3     3
```

etc, note that it is spaces and not tab, and this I can't change, since I'm working with a print out from ls-dyna
So I am using this script to remove the whitespaces before the numbers, since they have been giving me troubles when trying to format the numbers into a matrix and then i remove the empty lines afterwards

```
for line in input:
    print >> output, line.lstrip(' ')
```

but for some reason, I have 4442 lines (and here I mean writen lines, which is easy to track since they are enumerated) but the output only has 4411, so it removes 31 lines, with numbers I need
Why is this?

Comment: Can you show the kind of output you need?

Comment: It likely removes empty lines

Comment: The code you've provided appears fine. You say "*... it removes 31 lines, which I need...*" - How are you able to identify those?

Answer (score 0):

The `lstrip()` won't remove lines because it is used inside the `print` statement which will always append a newline character (the way you use it).  But the `for line in input` might step through the list of lines in an unexpected way, i. e. it could skip lines or combine them in a manner you didn't expect.

Maybe newline and carriage return characters result in this strange problem.

I propose to let the `.lstrip(' ')` away for testing and compare the output with the input to find the places where something gets changed.  Probably you should use `output.write(line)` to circumvent all the automatics of the `print` statement (especially appending newline characters).

Then you should use a special separator when outputting (`output.write('###' + line)` or similar) to find out how the iteration through the input takes place.

Comment: first of all thanks for the output.write command, like I said I am new to python, and have been wondering why it always made a newline, so that saved me a step in my programming.
the reason I now I have 4442 lines is because i can scroll down in the raw data and it is enumerated, but now that I don't have empty lines, the {.lstrip(' ')} output 4431 lines but not all of the 4431st line, besides that, there is not difference between the in and output

Comment: You should try ti find out which spots in the input result in losing lines.  Understanding what happens probably will already solve the issue.  You could use smaller input for this (half the file or similar).